# Single function call on scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, underscore.js

**Question Up Front:**
How can I change this script so that a neat, single function call occurs for either an up or down scroll?

**Here's a** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5G52/) **which represents the problem clearly.**

**The following script successfully pushes out an alert based on the direction of the user's scroll direction:**

```
//Firefox
$('html').on('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail;

    if (delta > 0) {

        alert('You scrolled up');

    } else if (delta < 0) {

        alert('You scrolled down');
    }

});

//Everything else
$('html').on('mousewheel', function(e){
var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

if (delta < 0) {

    alert('You scrolled down');

} else if (delta > 0) {

    alert('You scrolled up');
}
});
```

**But there's a problem:** 
When I scroll up or down, that function is called many times, rather than just executing neatly once, if the user scrolls up or down.

**So, my question is:** How can I change this script so that a neat, single function call occurs for either an up or down scroll?

**Known Solution Idea:**
Underscore.js offers a function

```
_.debounce(<function>,delay)
```

but this causes a delay and makes for a buggy fix.

Comment: Use timer to set variable and check that variable.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a simple example? I'm relatively new to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple flag based solution

```
var flag;
//Everything else
$('html').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    if (flag != 1 && delta < 0) {
        flag = 1;
        //alert('You scrolled down');
        $(".notify").append("<p>You scrolled down</p>");

    } else if (flag != 2 && delta > 0) {
        flag = 2;
        //alert('You scrolled up');
        $(".notify").append("<p>You scrolled up</p>");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NJaXf/)

Also you can combine both the handlers together

```
var flag;
$('html').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail;

    if (flag != 1 && delta < 0) {
        flag = 1;
        $(".notify").append("<p>You scrolled down</p>");
    } else if (flag != 2 && delta > 0) {
        flag = 2;
        $(".notify").append("<p>You scrolled up</p>");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J8RPL/)

Comment: And we have an excellent solution by the StackOverflow Pro, ladies and gentlemen. Thanks Arun.

Comment: Direction flag. Nice!

Comment: Works perfectly, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/U5G52/1/ (and I see he's just posted an updated fiddle as well)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one event, immediately.

If the user scrolls one direction, pauses for a while, and then continues to scroll, it will fire an event for each.

(Arun's answer only fires a new event if the direction has changed.)

I am unsure which you wanted. My personal inclination is to fire another event if the pause has been long enough.

```
var timeout;
var direction;

$('html').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        direction = 0;
    }, 500); //adjust as necessary

    if (delta < 0) {
        if(direction != -1) {
            direction = -1;
            $(".notify").append("<p>You scrolled down</p>");
        }
    } else if (delta > 0 && direction != 1) {
        if(direction != 1) {
            direction = 1;
            $(".notify").append("<p>You scrolled up</p>");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Arun beat you to it, but +1 for the effort ;)

Comment: @jt0dd, FYI, the solutions are functionally different. One scroll down, and Arun's will never ever give you another down event. Mine will...if it has been long enough. I'm not sure which your use case calls for.

Comment: Actually.. Check out my updated JSFiddle, are you sure? (the fiddle I added as a comment on his answer)

Comment: Edit: I see what you mean, yes, you're correct, and his does fix my situation, but I recommend that you keep your answer here because many users viewing this question may in fact need your version of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `one` event instead `on`

```
$('html').one('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
var delta = e.originalEvent.detail;

if (delta > 0) {

    alert('You scrolled up');

} else if (delta < 0) {

    alert('You scrolled down');
}

});

//Everything else
$('html').on('mousewheel', function(e){
var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

if (delta < 0) {

alert('You scrolled down');

} else if (delta > 0) {

alert('You scrolled up');
}
});
```